# How to check a certificate-based signature on a PDF document on Preview?

Tags: pdf, preview, digital-signature

Let's say I received a PDF document that supposedly was signed with a digital certificate, instead of pasting a hand-drawn signature. Can I use Preview to see the signature's properties and check if it is valid? If so, how?

Comment: I did some work previously with Cert based digitally signed PDFs and if I remember correctly, the validation of the signature is automatic because it's a) embedded within the document and b) checks with the issuing CA for validity.  If it doesn't check out, you'll get a warning.  Unfortunately, I don't have any samples that are signed with a cert to test on Preview - all the work was done in Acrobat.